# When a commandbutton is clicked How do I call a method in the managed bean to set a String before the onclick event fires?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When a commandbutton is clicked, How do I call a method in the managed bean to set a String before the onclick event fires? No matter what I try the method is called on the form refresh and not when the button is clicked.  I need the information set in the method to be available in the dialog called by the selectColorDlgWidget.show();

Here is the primefaces xhtml coede snip:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" id="editColorButton" onclick="#{chapUserPrefMB.setPrefTmpKey('CHAP_ColorOneOrMoreCls')}"/>
```

Here is the code fro the managed bean:

```
public String setPrefTmpKey(String tmpKey) { 
  currentTmpKey = tmpKey.trim();    
  currentTmpValue = getChapUserPrefString(currentTmpKey);
  return "selectColorDlgWidget.show();";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for ajax behavior or page reload?

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly; You want to run a client-side script, but the type of client-side script to run is decided on the server-side, but yet, you want the decision to be made before onClick, AFTER onClick has been used to make the decision?? Dude, serious design hole here

Answer (score 6):

You're making a conceptual mistake. Any EL expressions in attributes taking value expressions like the `onclick` attribute are invoked during generating the HTML output by JSF, and in the particular case of the `onclick` attribute thus *not* when the generated HTML DOM element is been clicked (instead, it will execute the piece of JavaScript code as already present in generated HTML output). If you want to invoke a backing bean method during the action event, then you should be using the `action` attribute instead. It takes a method expression instead of a value expression.

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" id="editColorButton"
    action="#{chapUserPrefMB.setPrefTmpKey('CHAP_ColorOneOrMoreCls')}" />
```

with

```
public void setPrefTmpKey(String tmpKey) { 
    currentTmpKey = tmpKey.trim();    
    currentTmpValue = getChapUserPrefString(currentTmpKey);
}
```

Then, to open the dialog on complete of the action, just use `oncomplete` attribute:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" id="editColorButton"
    action="#{chapUserPrefMB.setPrefTmpKey('CHAP_ColorOneOrMoreCls')}"
    oncomplete="selectColorDlgWidget.show()" />
```